# Android how can I set an alarm based on the time set in my sqlite database?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, time-format

I have an app which receives data from web service called tasks, tasks are then saved to my SQLite database. What I want to do next is query those tasks and then set an alarm based on the time they are set to be triggered. Let's say I have a task name "feed" and the time of the task to be triggered is at '09:00 AM'(I am using 'h:i A' format for my time). How can I convert this time format to something that can be read by the alarmManager?

```
public void setAlarm(int uniqueid, int duration) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(AlarmReceiver.ACTION_ALARM_RECEIVER);//my custom string action name
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, uniqueid, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
            + (duration * 1000), pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set for " + uniqueid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see if it works for you

```
Date mDate = new Date();
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
mCalendar.setTime(mDate);
mCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);

long alarmInTwoMinutes = mCalendar.getTimeInMillis();

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmInTwoMinutes, pendingIntent);
```

Update to setting at a specific time

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

long alarmInTwoMinutes = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

For repeating, you can use

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmInTwoMinutes, pendingIntent)
```

Comment: What if I want to trigger an alarm at a specific time from a timepicker? like "09:30 AM"?

Comment: is it repeating at this time everyday or one time trigger?

Answer (score 0):

```
String date_string = "09:00 AM";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
try {
    Date date = sdf.parse(date_string);
    long milliseconds = date.getTime();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

Use milliseconds.

Comment: It works but it is received directly after setting it..Like if I set the alarm 2 minutes from now. After setting it, it finishes immediately before the desired time. This is the line: alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, milliseconds, pendingIntent);

Comment: @Renboy yes, it is your time to fire alarm, read how Android AlarmManager works: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html